# Perimeters of isosceles triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Two non-congruent integer sided isosceles triangles have the same area and perimeter. The ratio of the lengths of the bases of the two triangles is 8:7. Find the minimum possible value of their common perimeter.

I have tried substituting the area for $a$ and the bases as $8x$ and $7x$. I then did Pythagoras and got the equation $15a=169x$. However, I still don't know how to find the minimum value. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the base of the first triangle $x$, the base of the second $\frac{8}{7}x$. The other side of the first and of the second will be $y$ and $z$. We'll have:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x+2y=\frac{8}{7}x+2z\\ 
x\sqrt{y^2-\frac{x^2}{4}}=\frac{8}{7}x\sqrt{z^2-\frac{16x^2}{49}}
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
x+2y=\frac{8}{7}x+2z\\ 
\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(y+\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{64}{49}\left(z-\frac{4x}{7}\right)\left(z+\frac{4x}{7}\right)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

[The first equation is the equality of the two perimeters, the second the one of areas(in which I calculated the height with the Pythagora Theorem). Then we squared the second equation and scomposed the two differences of squares]

Now there is a little trick! Multiply both sides of the second equation by $2$:
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x+2y=\frac{8}{7}x+2z\\ 
\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(x+2y\right)=\frac{64}{49}\left(z-\frac{4x}{7}\right)\left(\frac{8x}{7}+2z\right)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Since $\left(x+2y\right)$ and $\left(\frac{8x}{7}+2z\right)$ are equal for the first equation we can simplify them and obtain a linear system:
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x+2y=\frac{8}{7}x+2z\\ 
\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{64}{49}\left(z-\frac{4x}{7}\right)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now we can easily solve this for $(y,z)$ and obtain:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x=x\\ 
y=\frac{233}{210}x \\
z=\frac{109}{105}x 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Notice that since the sides are integer, at least $x=210$
Since the perimeter is:

$$P(x)=x+2y=x+2\frac{233}{210}x=\frac{338}{105}x$$

And the minimum is:

$$P(210)=676$$

:)

Comment: This really helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In isosceles $\triangle ABC$
let the base $|AB|=c$, 
$|AC|=|BC|=a$,
$S$ is the area and semiperimeter
$\rho=\tfrac12(a+a+c)=a+\tfrac c2$.

We have
\begin{align} 
S^2&=\rho(\rho-a)^2(\rho-c)
\\
S^2&=\tfrac14 \rho c^2(\rho-c)
.
\end{align}

Given two bases $7x$ and $8x$
and common $S$ and $\rho$,
we have 
\begin{align} 
\left(\frac{7x}2\right)^2(\rho-7x)
&=\left(\frac{8x}2\right)^2(\rho-8x)
,\\
\rho&=\frac{169}{15}\,x
,
\end{align}

corresponding perimeter is
\begin{align} 
p&=2\rho=\frac{338}{15}\,x
.
\end{align}

Thus $x=15$ provides
the minimal integer perimeter $p=338$,
but for the triangle with the base $c=7x=105$
the other side $a=(338-105)/2=\frac{233}2$ is not integer,
so we have to double it and get $x=30$
with $p=676$ as the answer.